# Haskell Recursion assignment

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm currently working on an assignment that focuses on recursive programming. I'm having trouble with two specific functions that use unique types. Number is a reverse list of a number and digit is the digit from Number.

```
Example of Number = [7,5] 57
Example of Digit [1]
```

addb is taking tge two lists provided, reverse them, and then have it changed into an int. The two ints are added together and the total is put into a list digit by digit in reverse.
Example:

```
>>> addb [5,7] [8,9] 0
[3,7,1]
```

convertNumList is meant to take a number and create a Number list.
Example:

```
>>> convertNumList 75
[5,7]
```

I was able to find a solution for convertNumList but it's not a recursive one. And my ideas for addb is along the same line for addb but im having trouble on how I should add the two lists recursively.  Apologies on my formatting this is my first time posting a question.

```
addb :: Number -> Number -> Digit -> Number
-- Fill in your code here
addb xs ys c
= [0,0,1]

convertNumList :: Int -> Number
converNumList 0 = []
convertNumList n =[n `mod` 10 ,n`div`10]
```

Comment: It's not clear what `addb` is supposed to be doing. Neither 75 + 98 or 57 + 89 is either 169 or 961.

Comment: @chepner I’m sorry for the lack of clarity and my bad math. addb is just taking the two lists provided, reverse them, and then have it them changed into an int. The two ints are added together and the total is put into a list digit by digit in reverse.

Comment: I'd say the intent of the assignment (given the `Digit` argument, which looks like a carry) is to perform the addition *without* first converting to and from an `Int`. For example, it looks like `addb [5, 7] [8, 9] 0` should return a list built using a recursive call, like `3 : addb [7] [9] 1`. I leave it as an exercise to figure out where the `3` and the argument `1` come from , as well as what happened to `5` and `8` from the original inputs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you're implementing decimal full adder

```
Prelude> let addb [] ys 0 = ys
Prelude|     addb xs [] 0 = xs
Prelude|     addb [] ys 1 = addb ys [1] 0
Prelude|     addb xs [] 1 = addb xs [1] 0
Prelude|     addb (x:xs) (y:ys) b = s: addb xs ys r
Prelude|                where (r,s) = divMod (x+y+b) 10
Prelude|

Prelude> addb [5,7] [8,9] 0
[3,7,1]
```

not sure it can be simplified further

Comment: There might a performance hit, but you can get away with a single base case `addb [] [] c = c`, two trivial recursive cases `addb xs [] c = addb xs [0] c` and `addb [] ys c = addb [0] ys c`, and the same main recursive case.

Comment: Yes, perhaps.  I wish there was a way to signal commutative property to reduce the cases by half.